# Alterar variavel em uma Task

Tags: android

Estou com esse método para ler uma página html, e ele está fazendo um Toast com o resultado. Porém queria que ele me retornasse o valor lido, ou colocasse em alguma variável, mas não obtive sucesso.

```
private class GrabURL extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    private final HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    private String Content;
    private String Error = null;
    private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Dialog.setMessage("Carregando. Aguarde...");
        Dialog.show();
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            Content = Client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Error = e.getMessage();
            cancel(true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Error = e.getMessage();
            cancel(true);
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        Dialog.dismiss();
        if (Error != null) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), Error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Source: " + Content, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            retorno = Content; // Essa variavel retorno é onde queria setar.
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lembrando que para você utilizar o `onPostExecute` você deve passar o tipo de resultado na herança.

1) Supondo que seja uma String, ele é o terceiro parâmetro:

```
extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
```

2) Sua função doInBackground deve retornar o tipo desse resultado, no caso uma String.

```
 protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {


         String result = "";

        return result ;
    }
```

3) Sua função onPostExecute deve estar assinada para receber uma String como parâmetro:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result)
```

Comment: Obrigado cara pela resposta, agora te faço a mesma pergunta que fiz para o Piovezan, teria como eu controlar o tempo máximo de execução da função?

Comment: Sim, teria como sim! Basta você implementar um timer dentro do doInBackground. Quando alcançar o tempo máximo, você chama a função this.cancel(true) (o true é para parar o processamento mesmo e não esperar terminar).  Nesse caso, você deve implementar a função onCancelled(String result) para que você receba o resultado obtido até então. Aqui está um exemplo de Timer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044726/how-to-set-a-timer-in-java

Answer (score 1):

É uma questão de *timing*. A variável `retorno` pode até estar recebendo o valor de `Content`, mas a parte do código que está lendo o valor de `retorno` deve estar tentando acessá-la antes da `AsyncTask` terminar de executar e portanto antes que ela tenha o valor desejado. Lembre-se: você não pode iniciar a execução da `AsyncTask` e esperar que o valor seja retornado imediatamente para você, pois a `AsyncTask` leva tempo para executar. Para isso existe o método `onPostExecute()`, que é executado justamente depois de `doInBackground()` ter se completado e os dados requisitados estão prontos e disponíveis.

Qual o uso que você irá fazer de `retorno`? Guardá-la no banco, em Shared Preferences, ou exibi-la em uma `TextView` na tela? Seja qual for, a sugestão é fazê-lo no próprio método `onPostExecute()`, que é o momento em que ela está com o valor que você deseja.

Comment: Obrigado era isso mesmo. Agora me veio outra dúvida, eu posso controlar o tempo máximo para executar essa função?

Comment: Você tem [algumas alternativas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391250/cancel-an-ongoing-connection-when-user-presses-back) para conseguir isso. Se quiser saber mais detalhes, abra uma nova pergunta no SO em português.